# SQL query <> populates even blank rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, toad

I have a 2 tables with 4,00,000 + records:
Table A (Column: Number and classification) and Table B (Column: Number and classification). I have to extract the code from both the table that are not equal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.number,
  a.classification,
  b.classification
FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b
  ON b.number = a.number
  AND a.classification != b.classification;
```

This query populates all the records that are **Not equal including rows that are BLANK**. I want a query without blank rows.

So I added another line to the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.number,
  a.classification,
  b.classification
FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b
  ON b.number = a.number
  AND a.classification != b.classification
  AND a.classification IS NOT NULL
  AND b.classification IS NOT NULL;
```

But the above query ran for 35 min and didn't generate any record. Can someone help me with an alternative?

Comment: mysql != sql server, please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? Be sure to include some `NULL` values where they can exists.

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Eg "extract the code from both the table that are not equal." is unintelligible. Use enough words, phrases & sentences to clearly refer to things & their parts. Please read & act on [mcve]. Read about what `outer join on` returns: what `inner join on` returns plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Also read about null in comparisons: for `!=` to be true neither operand can be null, so adding `and` `is not null` does nothing. Also `where` is applied after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this -> **a.classification <> ''**

```
select distinct a.number, a.classification, b.classification 
from TableA a left outer join 
TableB b on b.number = a.number
and a.classification != b.classification
AND a.classification <> '' AND a.classification IS NOT NULL
AND b.classification <> '' AND b.classification IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
select distinct a.number, a.classification, b.classification 
from      TableA a 
left join TableB b 
       on b.number = a.number
      and a.classification = b.classification
where b.number is null;
```

First you look for the ones that are equal, then you select those that aren't found.

Or, since you apparently want the b.classification value:

```
select distinct a.number, a.classification, b.classification 
from      TableA a 
left join TableB b 
       on b.number = a.number
where a.classification != b.classification;
```

Comment: Hi Honey, Thanks for the response. I am sorry for the confusion. but I guess the question is not clear. b.number will not be null. The comparison is between columns a.classification != b.classification. I don't want rows in which both a.classification and b.classification are blank.

Comment: You are thrown off by `where b.number is null`. This doesn't mean the value in the table is null, it means a record can't be joined to TableA, so either `number` or `classification` is unequal. You probably want the second query, if both TableA and TableB `classification` is `null`, the record gets ignored.